# Does filtering a table in Excel stored in SharePoint Online filter it for all the other people looking at the Sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint, multiple-users

I’ve used earlier versions of Excel where filtering a sheet meant that it would do the same for others on the network with the file open; is the same true of one stored in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 2):

I use Excel 365, and there has been a recent fix for this.
You now get the option to filter for everyone or just yourself.

This is the same for files on Teams or SharePoint.

[image]

Not everyone in my organization currently gets this option, which I'm guessing they must be due some updates, but cant say for sure.